# exec sp_getapplock - Different behaviour using go or without go

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, deadlock

we have a strange behaviour while using **sp_getapplock** (we tried to use this to solve a problem with a deadlock involving some insert while another session was trying to execute a ALTER SWITCH command).

Assuming having two sessions this is the first that start

```
use SKY_RGT

begin transaction

    declare @ResCode int  
    exec @ResCode = sp_getapplock   
        @Resource = 'SEMAFORO',   
        @LockOwner  = 'Session',   
        @LockMode = 'Exclusive'

    alter table TABLE_1 switch partition 501 
             to TABLE_2 partition 501
```

here is the situation that we have after the execution (result are coming from what we see querying sys.dm_tran_locks)

```
| resource | description | request_status | request_mode | session |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|     -    |  SEMAFORO   |     GRANT      |       X      |     1   |
|  TABLE_1 |             |     GRANT      |     Sch-M    |     1   |
|  TABLE_2 |             |     GRANT      |     Sch-M    |     1   |
```

then Session 2 start using this command

```
use SKY_RGT

begin transaction

    declare @ResCode int  
    exec @ResCode = sp_getapplock   
        @Resource = 'SEMAFORO',   
        @LockOwner  = 'Session',   
        @LockMode = 'Exclusive'

    insert into TABLE_2
    select      TIT.*
    from        TABLE_3 TIT
    where       TIT.SCE_COD = 501
```

and here is the lock situation after this

```
| resource | description | request_status | request_mode | session |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|     -    |  SEMAFORO   |     GRANT      |       X      |     1   |
|  TABLE_1 |             |     GRANT      |     Sch-M    |     1   |
|  TABLE_2 |             |     GRANT      |     Sch-M    |     1   |
|  TABLE_2 |             |     WAIT       |     Sch-S    |     2   |
|  TABLE_3 |             |     GRANT      |     Sch-S    |     2   |
```

as you can see it seems to ignore the application lock.

Different situation if we use the "GO" command after the lock.
Here is Session 1 using the GO (but in session 1 using or not the go is invariant because the application lock is acquired anyway)

```
use SKY_RGT

begin transaction

    declare @ResCode int  
    exec @ResCode = sp_getapplock   
        @Resource = 'SEMAFORO',   
        @LockOwner  = 'Session',   
        @LockMode = 'Exclusive'
    go

    alter table TABLE_1 switch partition 501 
             to TABLE_2 partition 501
```

and here the lock situation after this

```
| resource | description | request_status | request_mode | session |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|     -    |  SEMAFORO   |     GRANT      |       X      |     1   |
|  TABLE_1 |             |     GRANT      |     Sch-M    |     1   |
|  TABLE_2 |             |     GRANT      |     Sch-M    |     1   |
```

Then it comes session 2 using GO command

```
use SKY_RGT

begin transaction

    declare @ResCode int  
    exec @ResCode = sp_getapplock   
        @Resource = 'SEMAFORO',   
        @LockOwner  = 'Session',   
        @LockMode = 'Exclusive'
    go

    insert into TABLE_2
    select      TIT.*
    from        TABLE_3 TIT
    where       TIT.SCE_COD = 501
```

and here the lock situation after this

```
| resource | description | request_status | request_mode | session |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|     -    |  SEMAFORO   |     GRANT      |       X      |     1   |
|     -    |  SEMAFORO   |     WAIT       |       X      |     2   |
|  TABLE_1 |             |     GRANT      |     Sch-M    |     1   |
|  TABLE_2 |             |     GRANT      |     Sch-M    |     1   |
```

the last one is the situation that we expected but **why is working only using the go**?
The problem is that we have to transfer this kind of pattern inside stored procedures and inside SP is not possible to use the GO.

Any advice on this?

Thanks in advance.
Leonardo

Comment: Show us some actual go code please.

Comment: The GO code is in the second part of the question; is the same except for adding go at the end of the exec sp_getapplock instruction

Comment: Can you please verify that the application lock was released between tests? Note that session-level locks are non-transactional, and you must be very careful to always call `sp_releaseapplock` even if an error occurs.

Comment: We always checked at the end of every test that all the application locks were released. We checked it using sys.dm_tran_locks.

Comment: You're going to put this code into a stored procedure at some point, right? If so, then stop putting GO in your ad hoc testing code, because when that batch is wrapped in a stored procedure, GO can't be there. Also just because your tests have shown locks were released does not mean you should ignore best practices and not bother with sp_releaseapplock. Stepping back though, why are you using sp_getapplock? Why don't you just escalate the transaction to serializable?

Comment: @PaulWhite We tried also checking return code from `sp_getapplock` but there were no differences between the lock situation that i gave above... the problem still remains the different behaviour sp_getapplock has using or not GO instruction

Comment: @AaronBertrand we tried first using seralizable transaction but we had no success resolving the deadlock; we speaked with some expert on SQL Server and also him suggested to use sp_getapplock; we knoe that is not the best solution but appear to be the only one in this case

Comment: I'm still going to go back to my earlier comment. Why are you even testing never mind worried about the behavior when GO is involve? This is not how this code will work once deployed - GO isn't even transact-SQL, it's just a batch separator for the UI, and it is not possible to put GO inside a stored procedure.